# WPF MVVM - query about designing Models based on XSD

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, web-services, xsd

I have a small WPF application based on MVVM priniciples. So far I had dummy Model classes created in my app. Now I plan to call a Web Service that uses XSD. Looking forward I would like to use these Xsd Types as Models.

I can see atleast two way of doing this (could be more); for eg -

- add a reference to the Web Service. This means appropriate classes for types defined in the XSD will be generated by VS. I could then use these classes as Models. There is a potential namespace conflict (not a major one) when references are added if two or more web service are consumed in the app and these web services work with same XSD types.
- writing my own Model classes which can be populated based on the XML returned from WebService call. Model can validate the XML against XSD on intialization. This way no references are added and Web service can be called using HTTP GET/POST methods. But this involves manually updating models everytime the XSD changes.

Can you please advice on an optimal approach to using XSD Types as Models (based on your past experience with similar scenario of using types defined in XSD in MVC/MVVM app)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the scenario of your application. If you plan to distribute your client in all over the world and change often the service interface and data object, you have to find a way to build your model in the client from the xsd. 
Otherwise the first approach is very much easier.